# Mac OSX daemon for a task to maximize windows

Tags: macos, cocoa

I want a small functionality for all my Mac OSX application windows. When I double click on the title bar, either nothing happens or the application will get minimised(if the appropriate option is checked) instead, I want to create a functionality where it will get maximised completely(not full screen).

I am assuming that I should write a daemon for this but I am quite new to coding.

So my question is:

Can my "goal" be achieved by a daemon?

Answer (score 0):

No, it cannot. There is no way to implement this functionality with public APIs on Mac OS X.

Comment: can this be done by something else? Like a cocoa app?

Comment: No. Read my answer again - it isn't specific to any type of application.

Comment: The poster didn't stipulate the use of public APIs only.

Comment: A solution here is likely to require a significant amount of reverse engineering and nasty code injection hackery. For an inexperienced developer, like the OP, it's not going to be feasible at this point.

Comment: It could be done using Accessibility to get window information and a global event monitor to monitor clicks (both public APIs). But it's definitely not a trivial task.